# Connect variable with visibility (variable.visibility) in c#

Tags: c#, uwp

First I would like to apologize for the strange title, because I have no idea what to call what I like to achieve. But I have a grid element test1 that I want to collapse (hide), but instead of typing test1 it's a variable called IDElement. But how do I link IDElement with visibility?

```
 private void Collapse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var ID = button.Tag;

        string IDElement = "Test" + ID;

        Test1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        IDElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // should have the same result as Test1.visibility
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have a bunch of hard-coded Grid elements each with a "Collapse" button, and you want to write one click handler for all of the buttons which will hide the associated Grid.

You can get a reference to an element with a specific name by using the `FindName` method, like this:

```
var el = FindName("Test" + ID) as UIElement;
if (el != null)
{
    el.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

But I don't necessarily recommend this approach for what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I would like do but is there a better approach? I'm new to c# so do you use "as UIElement" in your code to make the variable usable in something like "variable.visibility"?

Comment: `FindName` doesn't return a `UIElement` type directly so I need to cast it to that type. I'm using `as` instead of `(Type)`-style cast because `as` will return `null` if the object cannot be cast to a `UIElement`. In your code, `IDElement` is of type `string` which does *not* have a `Visibility` property. You should probably revise basic C# OOP first so that you get more familiar with these concepts.